# Issuing multiple notifications Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to issue multiple `notifications` (After one notification has been issued, I want to add up on that).

I have been through the official docs, which describe that the notification number should be unique and should be used to update the notification. However I am finding it difficult to put a new line for a new `notification` (inboxStyle). Below is my code:

```
public void notificationFetch(int number, String greeting, String header){


        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        inboxStyle.addLine(Html.fromHtml("<i>italic</i> <b>bold</b>"));



        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setUsesChronometer(true).setTicker("tickerText").setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setLights(Color.BLUE, 200, 300).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Reminder").setContentText(header).setSubText(greeting).setNumber(number);





        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(number, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

**.setSubText()** does the required trick of appending more text, however I don't get new lines? Any ideas?

[image: Example Image:]

The rows (M.Twain) is a problem issue with me, I want different lines for new notifications.

Right now I get everything in a single line.

Here is what I get right now:

[image]

Comment: I did not get you, what you exactly want

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Notification noti = new Notification.InboxStyle(
  new Notification.Builder()
     .setContentTitle("5 New mails from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap))
  .addLine(str1)
  .addLine(str2)
  .setContentTitle("")
  .setSummaryText("+3 more")
  .build();
```

Here is the samples link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Notification notification = new Notification.InboxStyle(new Notification.Builder(context)
.setTicker(message)
.setSmallIcon(icon)
.setWhen(when)
.setContentTitle(title)
.setContentText(subTitle)
.setNumber(4)
.setContentIntent(intent))
.addLine("First Message")
.addLine("Second Message")
.addLine("Third Message")
.addLine("Fourth Message")
.setBigContentTitle("Here Your Messages")
.setSummaryText("+3 more")
.build();
```

Also go to official [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html) for more information.

Comment: Finding problems with pending intent. Can you give me a working example?

Comment: @user2822178 now explain u r issue in brief.

Comment: I want multiple notifications to group together one after the other like text in the image in my question, like messages from M.Twain are displayed. My intellisense in the IDE does not give me any option to use .addLine.

Comment: @user2822178 and first u plz upload your image.u r image is not uploaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47286/discussion-between-m-d-and-user2822178)